# $http.get is calling the wrong URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to call a URL from my *AngularJS* service. However, a specific call is not calling the correct URL.

This is the code that is doing the call, with a `console.log` printing the same URL as the call should be requesting:

```
this.getCategoriesByParent = function(parent) {
    console.log('http://localhost/cloqet_server/public/categories/subcategories/' + parent);
    return $http.get('http://localhost/cloqet_server/public/categories/subcategories/' + parent);
}
```

And the console output:

[image]

What can be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP uses port 80 by default. So your request to `http://localhost/...` is actually `http://localhost:80/...` be the :80 is left out.

Your local server is most likely not running on port 80 so you need to explicitly set the port

if your server is running on port 9000 your URL should be something like `http://localhost:9000/`

Comment: I have other functions with the URLs like the one, which is working fine (I am using port 80).
The problem is that the actual call is letting out the *cloqet_server/public/* part

Answer (score 0):

I located the error to be on the `API`.

When calling the URL, the `API` redirects you to the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

What server do you use for your api? If you are using apache check if you have .htaccess file that redirects you.